# How to populate an ArrayAdapter with a List of objects from a Firebase Database?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to populate my ListView with User objects from Firebase Database. I've seen some people use RecyclerView but I cannot get RecyclerView to work on my Android Studio (maybe i'm using incompatible dependencies).

Anyway here is my code:

```
// necessary imports

public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView usersList;
private DatabaseReference userDatabase;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    usersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_users);


    userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Populate ArrayAdapter with User objects from Firebase Database.
    ArrayAdapter<Users> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Users>(this, Users.class, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, userDatabase){

        // Populate here, don't know what to do.


    };

    usersList.setAdapter(Adapter);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Users.connectTo = list.get(i);
            Intent chatActivity = new Intent(List.this, ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(chatActivity);

        }
    });



}


}
```

- I know my ArrayList takes a String at the beginning, I will change that to Users.

  - ArrayAdapter parameters are not working, despite looking at the docs and it telling me this way.
  - Not sure how to properly implement RecyclerView
  - Not got much experience with Android Studio/Java.